# Error when I use template in class used afterwards in function: no viable constructor or deduction

Tags: c++, templates

I am making function Fold, which can accept different classes, e.g. Sum, which specify the type of operation done.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <list>

template <typename T>
struct Sum {
public:
    auto operator() (T init, std::list<int>::const_iterator first,
                    std::list<int>::const_iterator last) {
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            init += *it;
        }
        return init;
    }
};

template <typename Iterat, typename T, typename Operator>
 T Fold(Iterat first, Iterat last, T init, Operator func) {
    return func(init, first, last);
}


int main() {
    std::list<int> a{1, 2, 3, 6};
    std::cout << Fold(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 0, Sum()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

However, when I ran the code, I got the mistake "no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'Sum'"

The mistake can be managed two ways:

- If I use "int" instead of "template T" in class sum.
- If I specify in main() the type I want to use like:

---

```
Fold(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 0, Sum<int>())
```

---

Are there other ways to do something with this mistake? Neither of the two solutions I showed higher are suitable for my task

Answer (score 1):

Template arguments are deduced from the (function) arguments. Since `Sum` does not have arguments, the template arguments cannot be deduced. This is explained [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

All is not lost, however. `Sum`, as a class, does not use the template parameters. Only the `operator()` method does. Therefore, you can put template only the `operator()` method, and leave `Sum` as a non-template class.

For instance:

```
struct Sum {                                              
public:                                                   
    template <typename T>                
    auto operator() (T init, std::list<int>::const_iterator first,
                    std::list<int>::const_iterator last) {
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {         
            init += *it;                                  
        }                                                 
        return init;                                      
    }                                                     
};
```

I would also go as far as templating the iterator as well, like you did with Fold. The complete code example, with some additional usage examples, is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct Sum {
public:
    template <typename T, typename Iterat>
    auto operator() (T init, Iterat first, Iterat last) {
        for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
            init += *it;
        }
        return init;
    }
};

template <typename Iterat, typename T, typename Operator>
 T Fold(Iterat first, Iterat last, T init, Operator func) {
    return func(init, first, last);
}


int main() {
    std::list<int> a{1, 2, 3, 6};
    std::cout << Fold(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 0, Sum()) << std::endl;
    // init is a float. While the iterators return int.
    std::cout << Fold(a.cbegin(), a.cend(), 0.5 , Sum()) << std::endl;
    std::list<std::string> b{"1", "2", "3", "6"};
    std::cout << Fold(b.cbegin(), b.cend(), std::string(""), Sum()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```